# Why does attaching an $n$-cell give an (n-1)-connected pair?

Tags: algebraic-topology

There is the following result in algebraic topology sources:

Theorem. Let $X$ be obtained from $A$ by attaching an $n$-cell. Then $(X,A)$ is $(n-1)$-connected. That is, when $r<n$, any map $(D^r,\partial D^r) \rightarrow (X,A)$ is homotopic to a map whose image lies in $A$ relative to $\partial D^r$.

Here is a proof sketch I found in the book:
Let $e$ be the attached $n$-cell and $p$ be its center. Let $Y=X-\{p\}$ and $e^*=e-\{p\}$. Then we may partition $D^r$ into small pieces $D^r=\bigsqcup_\alpha D_\alpha$, where each $D_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to $D^r$, intersects each other at the boundary only, and for each $\alpha$, either $f(D_\alpha)\subset Y$ or $f(D_\alpha)\subset e$. Everything up to here is intuitive because I can simply take the subdivision via a sufficiently fine grid.

The book claimed that for each $\alpha$ s.t. $f(D_\alpha)\subset e$, we may use the fact that $(e,e^*)$ is $n$-connected and the Compression Lemma to find a homotopy rel $\partial D_\alpha$ from $f$ to a map to $e^*$. Then we may glue all those homotopies along the boundaries (since they are relative to them) and obtain a map into $Y$ homotopic to $f$. Then we may use a deformation retract to put that to $A$.

There is only one thing I don't understand - the invocation of the compression lemma on $f:(D_\alpha,\partial D_\alpha)\rightarrow (e,e^*)$ requires $f(\partial D_\alpha)$ to not contain $p$. That is, the subdivision has to be taken so that $f^{-1}(p)$ does not intersect any boundary of a small piece. I don't understand why this subdivision can be taken and couldn't seem to be able to get through this gap myself. So I'd really appreicate it if someone can show me how to fix this proof, or give me an alternative proof that does not rely on the Cellular Approximation Theorem (the book I am reading use this result to prove Cellular Approx Theorem, so I want to avoid circular arguments).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by: "whose image lies in $A$ *relative* to $\partial D^r$"? Isn't it the case that, by definition, for a map $f:(D^r,\partial D^r)\to(X,A)$, $f(\partial D^r)\subseteq A$?

Comment: That relative to $\partial D^r$ part is a description of the homotopy. So we want a map $g:D^r \rightarrow A$ such that $g$ is homotopic to $f$ via a homotopy $H$ s.t. $H(x,t)=f(x)$ as long as $x\in\partial D^r$.